# can't set image url from onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I have a problem with setting the image url from image ID

My button image is

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ButIm" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image1") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("image1") %>' OnClick="SelectImage" Width="100" Height="100" />
```

this image button works correctly

My event

```
protected void SelectImage(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string ImageName = ((ImageButton)sender).CommandArgument;
        imgVw.ImageUrl = ImageName;
        popImg.Show(); 
    }
```

My target popup

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="popImg" runat="server"
    PopupControlID="panel1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
    DropShadow="true" Enabled="true" CancelControlID="Cancel">
 </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

 <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
    <asp:Image ID="imgVw" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Kembali" class="art-button" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
 </asp:Panel>
```

My problem is that when I set a breakpoint on an event, I see that the url of imgVw.ImageUrl has the correct path but can't display an image. When I input the url manually on asp image ID like

```
<asp:Image ID="imgVw" ImageUrl="../image/image1.jpg" runat="server" />
```

popup can display the image perfectly

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What is the value of `imgVw.ImageUrl` when you view it in the debugger?

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered code? How does it look? Is it missing the path or is the path wrong?

Comment: value of imgVw.ImageUrl is path like i store on DB ("~//image//image1.jpg")
i have tested input manually url on imgVw.ImageUrl = "~/image/image1.jpg"; it still no image on my browser. but when i put the url on <asp:Image ID="imgVw" ImageUrl="../image/image1.jpg" runat="server" /> it works perfectly